# ORA-01722: invalid number using return in DML

Tags: oracle

The below is how I get the last identity value when I execute an insert while passing the name of the identity column dynamically (because I don't know what the name of the identity each time.)

```
set serveroutput on
/
DROP TABLE TEST_T
/
CREATE TABLE TEST_T
(
  TEST_ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ,
    NAME VARCHAR2(100)
)
/
DECLARE table_NAME_Id VARCHAR2(100);
trx_id NUMBER(4);
begin
table_NAME_Id:='TEST_ID';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
INSERT INTO TEST_T
(NAME)
VALUES
(''TEST'')
 RETURNING '||table_NAME_Id||' INTO :trx_id'
  RETURNING INTO trx_id;

dbms_output.put_line('ID: ' || trx_id);

END;
/
COMMIT
/
```

However if I make it in such way, it throw me an error, maybe because oracle wants an column and I am providing a variable ? or what is the reason of this error ? that is my question. and is there any other way to solve this error with a convert function other then above way ?

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 8

--THE BELOW IS THROWING THE ABOVE ERROR, WHY?
DECLARE table_NAME_Id VARCHAR2(100);
trx_id NUMBER(4);
begin
table_NAME_Id:='TEST_ID';


INSERT INTO TEST_T
(NAME)
VALUES
('TEST')
 RETURNING table_NAME_Id INTO trx_id;


dbms_output.put_line('ID: ' || trx_id);

END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does want a column, but it's throwing that specific error because it's trying to implicitly convert the *value* of the `table_NAME_Id` variable to a number. You can see that if you change that value:

```
DECLARE
  table_NAME_Id VARCHAR2(100);
  trx_id NUMBER(4);
BEGIN
  table_NAME_Id:='42';

  INSERT INTO TEST_T
  (NAME)
  VALUES
  ('TEST')
  RETURNING table_NAME_Id INTO trx_id;

  dbms_output.put_line('ID: ' || trx_id);
END;
/

ID: 42

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

With the variable set to your original value it's trying to do an implicit `TO_NUMBER('TEST_ID')`, which is always going to throw ORA-01722.

Although [PL/SQL name resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-A551A39D-7DF8-4525-BE0F-1F46FE04ED09) means that a column name takes precedence over a variable name, that doesn't help here as there is no column called `TABLE_NAME_ID` - so it happily uses the variable.

It can't use the *value* of the variable in place of the column name. You have to use dynamic SQL to provide a run-time column name (or any other object identifier).